# How to make all other routes working while one route is currently inserting huge data to database?

Tags: mysql, node.js, express, sequelize.js, ejs

I am curerntly working on a project in node.js with express as framework and mysql with sequelize ORM.

This is the method which uses an api to fetch lots of data and then i store all data in my database table.
The data is type of CSV and am using csv parser to parse the data and then store it.

```
getCSVDUMP: async (req, res) => {

        let userloged = req.session.userloged;
        if (userloged.type == 'Admin') {
            const destroy = await db.symboltable.destroy({ truncate: true })
                .then((response) => {
                    console.log(response);
                })
                .catch((err) => {
                    console.log(err);
                })
            await db.apitoken.findOne({
                order: [
                    ['id', 'DESC']
                ]
            }, { limit: 1 })
                .then(async data => {
                    if (data) {
                        const instrumentURL = "https://api.kite.trade/instruments";
                          requestp.get({
                            url: instrumentURL,
                            headers: {
                                'Authorization': 'token ${data.api_key}:${data.access_token}'
                            }
                        }, async (error, result) => {
                            if (result) {
                                const csvdata = result.body;

                                fs.writeFileSync('symbols.csv', csvdata, 'utf8', (error, result) => {
                                    if (error) console.log(error)
                                    console.log(result);
                                })

                                let stream = fs.createReadStream('symbols.csv');

                                let csvstream = fastcsv.parse({ headers: true })
                                    .on('data', async (data) => {
                                        var symboldata = await db.symboltable.create(data)
                                            .then((response) => {
                                                console.log("added to symbol table")
                                            })
                                            .catch((err) => {
                                                console.log(err)
                                            })

                                    })
                                    .on('end', () => {
                                        res.redirect('/api_tokens');
                                    })
                                stream.pipe(csvstream);
                            }
                            else {
                                console.log(error);
                            }
                        })
                    }
                })
                .catch(err => {
                    console.log(err);
                })
        } else {
            res.redirect('/logout');
        }
    },
```

This operation is normally done by admin.

But whenever this operation is carried out, i cannot access my other routes like login or any other database operations.

How can i fix this issue?

If the solution is by using async and await, please get me tutorial link or any examples.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Short version: we don't know. You're going to have to figure out what your Node server is doing when it's not responding to requests. Also, you haven't provided much information. How long does the server stop responding to requests? Is it all requests or just those that use the database?

I have some ideas that might help.

First of all, there's a call to `writeFileSync`, so your server will ignore requests while it's writing the CSV data. It looks like you previously used the asynchronous version of this method because you're passing it a callback. The synchronous version doesn't take a callback, which means you're not actually checking for errors here.

Your code is mixing and matching async/await and promises. Not sure it's all really kosher. I suggest you pick one or the other. (There are plenty of tutorials on async/await out there, just Google for it.)

Another possibility is that your server isn't responding to requests because it's legitimately doing something else. A Node server that is processing one request can only switch to a different request if needs to wait on I/O. If it's parsing a CSV file, it can service other requests when it's waiting to retrieve the CSV data from its source, but not when it's actually parsing that data. If this is your problem, you could consider moving the fetch/load process into a separate process that you launch or trigger from your Node server.

Finally, it's possible that your database is the bottleneck and that the data load process causes other requests to block because the database is busy loading your data. This might be a problem if other requests need to access the same table into which you're loading the data.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I am just a beginner in node.js. After completely parsing the csv file each row get uploaded to the table and i think it takes 2-3 minutes to complete the data as it may have 64k rows. When this processes is running, it blocks other request which needs database operations. So it affects only the requests which need databse.

Comment: It could be that you only have one available connection to the database, and so other database requests have to wait for the load to complete. Or Sequelize can't handle more than one request at a time, and it's busy processing all your calls to create. Or locks on the database and/or the tables are preventing the other queries from running. By the way, 2-3 minutes to create 64K rows is really slow. I think that, because of how you're calling create, you may be acquiring a database connection, inserting, and then committing every row separate. Look for some bulk-insert API.